# How to say that the navigation is approximate?

Tags: meaning, expressions, word-usage, phrase-requests

I have an app that is an index for businesses, so the user can search for a business and navigate to that business.

I have two types of coordinates to the business:

1. Accurate coordinates, which navigate the user exactly to the
   business building.
2. Inaccurate coordinates, which navigate the user to a place near the business.

So if the coordinates are the second one, I want to write next to the navigation button that it's approximate navigation or not 100% accurate. How could I say that in English ?

thanks

Comment: This might be better for ELL.SE, but I'm not sure.  I don't think "accurate" or "coordinate" are the words you mean, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean to say.  A coordinate is a numerical address, not any sort of directions.

Comment: the coordinate is numerical address, for example (38.54,39.25), but some times this point will not navigate the user exactly to the business building , maybe to a place near the business ! so I want to write next to the navigation button that it's not accurate !

excuse me what do you mean with ELL.SE ?

Comment: In that case, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by navigate--show an area on a map?  But why not have two button labels like: "Navigate" and "Navigate*" with an explanation somewhere that * means location is approximate.  This site I meant was: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you for your response, what I mean with navigate: the app will send the business location to google maps then google maps will navigate the user to the business. so should I write next to the navigation button "location is approximate" ?

Comment: that seems fine as for english.  if you have questions about aesthetics/design, this is the right site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be safe calling the second type of coordinates **approximate** coordinates.

> **Approximate** (adjective):
>
> 1. near or approaching a certain state, condition, goal, or standard
> 2. nearly exact; not perfectly accurate or correct
>
> ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/approximate?s=t))

On the other hand, the first type of coordinates could be called **exact** coordinates.

> **Exact** (adjective)
>
> 1. strictly accurate or correct
> 2. precise, as opposed to approximate
>
> ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exact?s=t))